# Openstack Magnum ERROR: The Parameter (octavia_ingress_controller_tag) was not defined in template

Tags: kubernetes, openstack, kubernetes-ingress

While creating k8s cluster using magnum I m getting this error and when I m giving `octavia_ingress_controller_tag` as a perimeter its showing invalid argument

I tried creating a cluster from openstack UI as well as cmd

cmd I used while creating a cluster

```
openstack coe cluster template create k8s-cluster-template \
                           --image coreos \
                           --keypair DevController \
                           --external-network Public \
                           --dns-nameserver 8.8.8.8 \
                           --flavor m1.tiny \
                           --docker-volume-size 10 \
                           --network-driver flannel \
                           --coe kubernetes \
                           --octavia_ingress_controller_tag ‘’ 


openstack coe cluster create k8s-cluster \
                      --cluster-template k8s-cluster-template \
                      --master-count 1 \
                      --node-count 2
```

Answer (score 1):

CoreOS image can be used for K8s cluster start from Magnum 9.1.0 as mentioned in the compatibility matrix of this wiki https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/Magnum